# How to check redis server version from client terminal?

Tags: server, redis, version

we use `** server --version**` to check version from the host computer
but this command not works in client computer

```
(error) ERR unknown command `redis-server`, with args beginning with: `--version`,
```

Comment: Is the Redis client software installed, and which version of it are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

after the connecting to server
type this command

```
> info
```